# Unity - Leaderboard data is delayed when showing up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner to coding. A friend of mine used to help me but now he's busy so I have to do things alone. The game has a function that remember the name the player input before playing the game as well as the score of the player. Right now, my problem is that when I play a game, it doesn't show up in my leaderboard scene. And then when I play another round with a different name, I can see the previous score but not my current one. It's like the data is delayed to appear.

```cs
void ReplaceRank(string player, int currentScore) {
    string oldName;
    int oldScoreNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (currentScore > scores[i]) {
            highscoreShow.enabled = true;
            oldScoreNumber = scores[i];
            oldName = PlayerPrefs.GetString(oldPlayerName[i]);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(oldScore[i], currentScore);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(oldPlayerName[i], player);
            Debug.Log(currentScore);
            if (i <= 9) {
                ReplaceRank(oldName, oldScoreNumber);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void GetAllKeys() {
    oldScore = new List<string>();
    oldPlayerName = new List<string>();
    scores = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 11; i < 21; i++) {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("score" + i + "Name", "") == "") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("score" + i + "Name", "");
        }
        oldPlayerName.Add("score" + i + "Name");
        oldScore.Add("score" + i);
        scores.Add(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score" + i, 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this seems trivial its not , saving is kinda tricky, they are a few things you can do to make it easier e.g you should save the scores as a list

Saving

1. add scores to list
2. convert list of scores to Json
3. save json string in player prefs

Loading

1. get json string from player prefs
2. convert Json to list
3. updated list in script

wrote this class quickly.. its tested and works but you might have to modify it to suit your needs and improve it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;



namespace ScoreBoard
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerScore

    {
        public string Name;
        public int Score;

        public PlayerScore(string name, int score)
        {
            Name = name;
            Score = score;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    // we need to store list of scores in a container class so we can change it to json 
    public  class PlayerScoresRankedListContainer
    {
        public  List<PlayerScore> PlayerScoresRanked = new List<PlayerScore>();
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class ScoresRanked  : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static PlayerScoresRankedListContainer PlayerScoresListContainer =new PlayerScoresRankedListContainer();

        public void Awake()
        {
            //example of usage 

            //get saved items
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerScoresRanked").Length > 0)
            {
                PlayerScoresListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked = GetSortedListFromPlayerPrefs();
                DebugShowScores();
            }
            else
            {
                //test the class asving items 

                AddScoreToRankedList("player1", 1000);
                AddScoreToRankedList("player2", 20);
                AddScoreToRankedList("player3", 100);
                SaveListAsJSONInPlayerPrefs();
            }

        }

        private void AddScoreToRankedList(string player, int currentScore)
        {

            var score = new PlayerScore(player, currentScore);

            if (DoesScoreAlreadyExist(score))
            {
                //we remove a score if it already exists so we can updated it 
                //you might not need this maybe you just want to keep adding scores
                PlayerScoresListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == score.Name);
                PlayerScoresListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked.Add(score);

            }
            else
            {
                PlayerScoresListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked.Add(score);
            }


        }

        public void SaveListAsJSONInPlayerPrefs()
        {


           var jsonlist = JsonUtility.ToJson(PlayerScoresListContainer);

            Debug.Log("LOG ITEMS BEING SAVED: "+jsonlist);

            PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerScoresRanked", jsonlist);
        }

        public List<PlayerScore> GetSortedListFromPlayerPrefs()
        {
            var jsonlist = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerScoresRanked");

            var ListContainer = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerScoresRankedListContainer>(jsonlist);

            var listsorted = ListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();

            return listsorted;
        }

        public bool DoesScoreAlreadyExist(PlayerScore scoreToChcek)
        {
            if (PlayerScoresListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked.Exists(x => x.Name == scoreToChcek.Name))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void DebugShowScores()
        {
            foreach (var playerScore in PlayerScoresListContainer.PlayerScoresRanked)
            {
                Debug.Log(playerScore.Name + " " + playerScore.Score);
            }
        }

    }

}
```